# Vector fields of a physical quantity

Tags: vector-fields

I had this small confusion -
The components of a vector field representing a physical quantity must have the same physical dimension right? 
for example- the radius vector has the unit of length along all three components and so it does represent the position of an object.
What about
$$c(r(r) + cos(\phi) (\phi) + z(k))$$ ?

This can't represent any physical quantity right? whatever the dimension of constant 'c' may be.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12333/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Are the $(r)$, $(\phi)$ and $(k)$ terms supposed to be unit vectors?

Comment: Yes,(r), (ϕ) and (k)  are the unit vectors in the cylindrical coordinate system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the expression you are trying to write is 
$$c \left( r \cdot\hat r + \cos \theta \cdot \hat  \theta + z \cdot\hat k \right)$$

As you say this will not represent a physical quantity since since $\cos \theta$ is dimensionless and $r$, $k$ have dimensions of length.

The expression
$$c \left( r \cdot\hat r +  z \cdot\hat k \right)$$ would be an allowed physical quantity ( which quantity would depend on the dimensions of $c$ ) and so would also $c  \cos \theta \cdot \hat  \theta $ be.

Remember that the unit vectors are dimensionless quantities $\hat r = \frac{\vec r}{r}$ so all the dimensionality is carried by their pre-factors.

If that dimensionality is the same for all terms, then the quantity makes mathematical (and physical) sense.